# FTM screen cant remove battery

Tags: battery

my phone says FTM it suggests taking the battery out but I cant remove my battery so now what do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Even you didn't mention which phone is that, I guess it is a ZTE device. Well, FTM mode or Factory Test Mode  is like fastboot mode, is used to flash the phone. So I wondering how you get there. To get the phone out there, remove the battery. If it's a non-removable battery, just hold power button + volume down for a certain seconds.

Comment: what if you cant use your volume down button what do you do then

Comment: Try the command fastboot reboot. Otherwise get the buttons fixed.